# torchvision: transforms.Normalize(mean, std )

Tags: pytorch

tengo una data de imágenes de números a blanco y negro, ya se transformó las imágenes en escala de grises transforms.Grayscale(), luego a tensores transforms.ToTensor() y luego normalizar cada tensor con respecto a su media y su desviación. esta parte no se como indicarla en el código. y finalmente se redimensionan los tensores.

```
def dataset(data):

    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),            
        transforms.Normalize(mean,std),
        transforms.Resize(90)

    ])

    dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=data, transform=transform)
```

Hice un pequeño ejercicio con un tensor, pero no se como integrarlo al código anterior (soy aprendiz).

```
x2 = torch.tensor([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
                  [ 4.,  5.,  6.]]]
                 )

def normalizar(x2):
  mean=x2.mean()
  std=x2.std()
  transform = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.Normalize(mean,std)
    ])

  transform(x2)

  return transform(x2)

print(transform(x2))
```